# jQuery .is() :first showing different behavior from :last

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Can anyone explain to me what the heck is going on with the jQuery .is() function?

I have a situation where I'm checking to see if an element is the first of a group of elements that I have selected.

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>third</li>
      <li>last</li>
   </ul>
</div>

$('div > ul > li').first().is(':first') or
$('div > ul').find('li:first').is('li:first')
```

returns false.... what is going on here?

```
$('div > ul > li').last().is(':last') or
$('div > ul').find('li:last').is('li:last')
```

return true

Comment: `.last().is(':last')` I get `false` too here.

Comment: hmm the html block of code is much simplied than the version than I'm working with, maybe it has something to do with other html elements that are on the page.

Comment: Btw, when the jQuery object didn't select anything, you will get `true`, e.g. `$('#I_dont_exist').first().is(':first') // true`. Check if your jQuery object contains any elements for those cases where you get `true`.

Comment: naw I tried in jsfiddle $('div > ul').find('li:last').is('li:last') returns true

Comment: Have you tried doing $('div > ul > li').first().is('li:first')

Comment: Yeah it returns true, is() the selector doesnt have any references back to the left most chain of the jquery object and checks the entire page again. I got it now :) Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector `:first` just selects the first element from all elements on the page. That one is `<html>`, try running `$(":first")`. `:last` works in your case because the last `<li>` also happens to be the last element on the whole page.

You might want `:first-of-type` or `:first-child` instead.

Comment: Yeah I decided to use :first-child but I want to know why li:first wont return true either

Comment: @BruceLim `li:first` will match the first `li` in the ENTIRE document.

Comment: This is correct. Notice that if the last element on OP's page is a LI element (as it seems), then that means that OP didn't put SCRIPT elements at the bottom `:)`

Comment: @Bruce Lim: In your posted markup it returns `true`, but that's also a coincidence since the first `li` in the group is also the first `li` on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/MvWcv/1/
When you select ':first', it means that you select the FIRST NODE OF WHOLE DOCUMENT.
':last' is also pointing the last node of whole document, which is "last".

Thus it should be

`$('div > ul > li').first().is('div > ul > li:first')`

and

`$('div > ul > li').last().is('div > ul > li:last')`

Comment: That looks so redundant :( I am going to use :first-child and :last-child. I guess that should be the correct way since is a css pseudo class.

Comment: @Bruce Lim: What are you trying to accomplish? `.first().is(":first")` doesn't look very useful anyway.

Comment: not exactly my code that I'm using but I was writing the question in a way to show that I was selecting the first element. I wasn't trying to disrespectful in anyway :)

Comment: I tried to explain what exactly ':first' and ':last' selectors point. Bruce misunderstood that ':last' worked but ':first' doesn't. But the truth is that neither are wrong. (':last' worked accidentally because <li>last</li> is really the last node of whole document.